# Standard Output in Java

Tags: java, logging, outputstream

I need to get the console output of a JAR file in my GUI application. Im running the JAR calling the command line from my GUI application, as you can see below:

```
String cmdLine = "java -jar myjar.jar";
myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myProcess.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) { //do something }
```

In myjar.JAR,  I created a CustomPrintStream in order to log everything to a txt file AND the console. Here it is:

```
public class CustomPrintStream extends PrintStream
{
static private FileHandler fileTxt;

Logger logger;

public CustomPrintStream()
{
    super(new ByteArrayOutputStream());

    try
    {
        this.logger = Logger.getLogger("LOGGER");
        this.logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        fileTxt = new FileHandler("Logging.txt");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do nothing!
    }

    CustomRecordFormatter formatter = new CustomRecordFormatter();
    this.fileTxt.setFormatter(formatter);
    this.logger.addHandler(fileTxt);

    ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
    ch.setFormatter(formatter);
    logger.addHandler(ch);

    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
}

@Override
public void print(String s)
{
    super.print(s);
    logger.info(s);
}
}
```

Also, I set the standard output of myjar.JAR to the custom stream:

```
System.setOut(CustomPrintStream);
```

Running the JAR file in windows command line works fine, but when I try to get console output programmatically in my GUI application it just doesn't work.

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI applications doesn't have a "console". Why don't you try instead adding the jar as a reference to your GUI project and call the right function programatically?

Comment: I'm not adding as reference because someone else is implementing the JAR file and my GUI app should be as independent as possible. In future, the JAR file will be updated several times while my GUI app will not. The flow of information would be: GUI -> Call JAR file as a process -> Get Console Output -> Return to GUI

Comment: The problem you describe can be easily solved using interfaces. Just define an interface for the functions you need to call and forget about the implementation.